# How to copy file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I use ASP.net and have a .docx file in website:

```
Server.MapPath("~") + @"Files\tmp.docx".
```

I want copy this file to

`Server.MapPath("~") + @"Files\Docx\"` with "D210" named.

How to copy this file and rename it?

Comment: what do you mean `remove name`?

Comment: @mahditahsildari: I typed wrong. i want Rename new file

Comment: @AhmazKazemi did you test my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do IO job so do not forget to add `Using System.IO;`
and this is the code you need:

```
//1.Prepare the name for renaming
string newName = "D210";

//2.Create the Folder if it doesn't already exist
if(!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~")+@"\Files\Docx\"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~")+@"\Files\Docx\");

//3.Copy the file with the new name
File.Copy(Server.MapPath("~") + @"Files\tmp.docx",Server.MapPath("~")+@"\Files\Docx\"+newName+".docx");
```

Comment: I guess "example1" should be "D210". That is what he wants too.

Comment: Also looking at his question he wants to copy the file to application root\Files\Docx\ so you might want to change the `Server.MapPath(".")` to `Server.MapPath("~")` since you don't know if the .aspx is located in the root.

Comment: Yes @Rutix you've got sharp eyes unlike me ;) I hadn't mention it, thanks pal.